# module.eks.data.aws_iam_session_context.current: Still reading... [11m10s elapsed]

Tags: terraform

I have an issue with my terraform code for EKS

I downloaded the EKS module from terraform.io and calling that from my local

I am passing IAC role like this in my eks code provider section:

role_arn = "arn:aws:iam::${var.account_id}:role/iacServiceAccess"

the iacServiceAccess role has full access to create services

running terraform plan/apply from an ec2 that has

"Action": "sts:AssumeRole",
"arn:aws:iam::******:role/iacServiceAccess",

but when terraform plan goes into cycle and it keeps going:

2024-03-16T13:46:43.080Z [DEBUG] ReferenceTransformer: "module.eks.module.kms.data.aws_partition.current[0] (orphan)" references: []
2024-03-16T13:46:43.080Z [DEBUG] ReferenceTransformer: "module.eks.module.kms.data.aws_caller_identity.current[0] (orphan)" references: []
[0m[1mdata.aws_ssm_parameter.ssm_parameter_account_id: Still reading... [10s elapsed][0m[0m
[0m[1mmodule.eks.data.aws_iam_session_context.current: Still reading... [10s elapsed][0m[0m

Comment: error --> Plugin did not respond   with module.eks.data.aws_iam_session_context.current